# Eclipse project can't find itself in class path

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I'm using Eclipse Juno and trying to import a java project created with an earlier version of Eclipse on a different operating system. After importing the project and trying to run one of the java files, I get this error: The project: OldProj which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
But the file I'm trying to run is in the OldProj project, so it's saying it can't find itself.
It's a stand-alone project. It doesn't reference anything outside itself, not does anything else reference it. It is the only project in the workspace, in both versions.

I tried importing the project through the Import... command. I tried creating a new project and just copying the source files over. Both get this result. The project still runs fine on the earlier version.

This is a new install of Eclipse, so perhaps I missed a setting or two. Does anyone know what I missed?